# How do I create a tooltip showing a validation error pointing to a field when the submit button is pressed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a form with Javascript validation. I have been able to do validation for all the fields but for now, I have only shown the errors in an alert() when I submit the form.

I am wondering if there is a way to create a sort of tool-tip that point to the field and states the error that occurred during submission for each specific field.

I figured that I am supposed to save this error in a variable but I want to present it in a visually pleasing way.

Here is some of my code:

```
<script>

function check_name_field(){
                var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
                if(txtName==""){
                    var errName = "Please enter your full name";
                    //some code to show a tool-tip of the error
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            }

</script>

<form class="newUserLogin" id="newUserLogin" method="post" action="signNewVis.php" onsubmit="return check_name_field();">

<input type="text" name="Name_user" id="txtName">
<input type="submit" value="submit">    

</form>
```

[This image is basically what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmfHV.png)

Comment: You can't if the Form is sent. So (1) `preventDefault` behavior, (2) create in CSS a tooltip and validation message (3) execute validation, if error show error, else allow submit.

Comment: That can be done, but how exactly do you create these? Should I stylize a div to look like a tooltip?

Comment: You can use bootstrap and by adding a tooltip to the controls in case its fails

Comment: Like @mbadeveloper said, I would create the tootip in HTML and CSS first, using Bootstrap or  any other library. Then add JS behavior, answers here seem to be focusing on the JS behavior, so search how to create a tooltip on SO or some other site, and use the answers below to create the behavior, you can't do everything in one single post, I think that's why they voted down.

Comment: Oh alright, I see. That makes sense @carkod. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks also @mbadeveloper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least you can do is to add title value for the component as follows:-
1) Create a div with absolute position
2) Add innerHtml as the above error msg
3) set div top left as that of input control
4) display it near the control or on hover of the control
5) write script to remove once click outside

```
<script>

function check_name_field(){
                var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName');
                if(txtName.value==""){
                    var errName = "Please enter your full name";
                    //div.innerHTML = errName;
                    //div.top =txtName.top; div.left= txtName.left;

                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            }

</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so I should simply create a div and send the error to be displayed in that div. Then style it to look like a tooltip? However, I am confused about what the "div.top =txtName.top" means

Comment: txtName is now your textbox control and the div.top =txtName.top gives the tooltip div same coordinate as that of the control, so that div is shown at the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it, like have the placeholder(element) to place your message in DOM. Do some CSS to style that element as tooltip. And then you can include some code to the respective error element like

```
<element>.style.display = "block"; // to show

<element>.style.display = "none"; // to hide
```

to show the element when the error occurs.

The solution above does positioning the error element and showing it on error.